# Disable Arrow Keys In emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

I want avoid using arrow keys for navigation within emacs however due to being an habit its difficult to switch to native key bindings of emacs for navigation. I would rather like to disable arrow keys in order to avoid it completely. How can i disable arrow keys in emacs?

Comment: Disabling cursors is one thing, but doing `C-s` `C-r` search style navigation, is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this Elisp code at the bottom of your `~/.emacs` startup file:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<left>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<right>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<up>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<down>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-left>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-right>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-up>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-down>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<M-left>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<M-right>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<M-up>"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<M-down>"))
```

and then restart Emacs.  If you don't want to disable the Ctrl (`C-`)and Alt (`M-`) variants, just leave those sections out.

Answer (score 1):

This link is prob also relevant (its what I have just started using):

http://danamlund.dk/emacs/no-easy-keys.html

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)